# Can OpenTelemetry (Java) be configured or otherwise convinced to tag spans with MDC values?

Tags: java, open-telemetry

Requests to our application are associated with a customer ID.  This metadata value is available during the scope of the request via MDC (slf4j) and used for logging and a handful of other telemetry/observability/meta sorts of activities.  It would be useful for us to have that value as a tag on all OTEL spans.

1. Is there a way to configure OTEL to automatically tag spans with values from MDC context.  Ideally I'd be able to configure OTEL with a set of key pairs providing the name of the tag I'd like to add to the Span and the MDC key who's associated value should be set as the value of the tag.
2. If the configuration-based approach articulated isn't possible, is there the ability to place a small amount of code at the start of a request (i.e. in a filter on a servlet container or similar) which would copy desired MDC values to OTEL context such that all spans created in the request thereafter would implicitly be created with / inherit those tags.

If there's another way to achieve tagging all spans for a request more or less implicitly I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance for any help / guidance you can provide.

Comment: The MDC instrumentation currently only goes the other way as demonstrated in this document: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/logger-mdc-instrumentation.md.  Certainly sounds like an interesting idea.  Consider [adding an issue](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/new/choose) or [write an extension](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/examples/extension/README.md).

Comment: Thanks @TylerB - any thoughts on the fallback approach (2) above?  If we can do that cleanly we can try and generalize it as an extension.

Comment: @JamesCourtney Have been able to figure out how to add MDC values to the span as attributes using an extension? I'm currently trying to do that as well.

Comment: @Zak - nope - and I've admittedly not be pursing it since this convo fizzled out and the colleague trying to do this moved on to other priorities.  It does look like Rafael Winterhalter has provided a respectably complete and recent response below as of the last 24 hours so perhaps it's worth dusting off the effort and giving it a go.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it seems like you are using the OTel agent. To achieve what you are doing, you would need to implement an extension for the agent. Within a servlet filter, you could for instance read the MDC for each request and tag the current span, similar to [this sample extension](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/examples/extension/src/main/java/com/example/javaagent/instrumentation/DemoServlet3Instrumentation.java). Note that the advice code is injected into the targeted class loader such that you'd be able to call the MDC class as expexted from regular code within the advice.

To inherit the property throughout all child spans, you'd additionally need to register a custom SpanProcessor, [similar to this sample](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/examples/distro/custom/src/main/java/com/example/javaagent/DemoSpanProcessor.java). You'd need to copy the attribute from the parent span within the onStart merhod.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Rafael Winterhalter - this effort has been on the back burner for a while now but we'll give your seemingly pretty thorough suggestion(s) a good look when we pick stuff back up.

Answer (score 0):

Since MDC is statically accessible, I believe you can implement a `SpanProcessor` that adds the desired attributes to `span` in the `onStart` method.

Comment: How would that work? You don't have access to MDC class in the agent classpath. How would you be able to grab MDC values from within an extension?

Comment: Hmm. Good point.  You can probably hack around this problem using method handles/reflection. Otherwise Raf's answer is probably the best approach.